# Counting number of recursive calls in fibonacci, in C

Tags: c

I faced the following question:

Calling `fib(8)` (below), how many recursive calls are made (ignoring the first) ? And what's the return value?

```
int fib (int n) {
    if (n==0 || n==1) return 1;
    else return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

So I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int r = 0;

int fib (int n) {
    printf("k: %d fib n: %d", r++, n);
    if (n==0 || n==1) {
        printf("\n");
        return 1;
    } else { 
        printf(" +\n");
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); 
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int f = fib(n);
    printf("\nreturn: %d\n", f);
    return 1;
}
```

Using this I'll answer `fib(8) = 34` the number of recursive calls is `66`.

Am I right?

Comment: This method of fibonacci has an exponential time complexity.

Comment: I think it will be 67 recursive calls if you change `r++` to `++r` because your first call will report `0`.

Comment: Although technically the first call (from `main`) isn't recursive, so 66 may be the answer that the teacher is looking for.

Comment: 34 is not the 8th term, it is either the 9th or 10th, depending on whether the Fibonacci series starts at 0 or at 1. Please see the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Comment: @WeatherVane That's another zero-based/off-by-one issue. `34` is correct if you count the terms starting from the zeroth term, `1`.

Comment: If you're worried about @user3386109's comment it is best, in your answer to just thoroughly specify how you decided to count.

Comment: @Caleb if you are believer in the use of "zeroth" you might be a believer in multiple universes too. However the initial term of a mathematical series is the first term and not the zeroth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### First of all Total fib calls = 67

recursive calls is = 66

```
                   fib(5)   ---root-first call ,not consider recursive call 
                 /           \     
           fib(4)             fib(3)   
         /      \                /     \
     fib(3)      fib(2)       fib(2)    fib(1)
    /     \        /    \       /    \
```

-
because first call is not considered as recursive call

### Now lets derive a formula for calculate number of times fib(n) is called

Let f(n) be the number of calls made to calculate fib(n).

If n < 2 then f(n) = 1.

Otherwise, f(n) = 1 + f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)

So, f is at least O(fib(n)). In fact, f(n) is 2 * fib(n) - 1.

We show this by induction:

Base cases (n < 2, that is, n = 0 or n = 1):

f(n) = 1 = 2 * 1 - 1 = 2 * fib(n) - 1.

Induction step (n >= 2):

f(n + 1) = f(n) + f(n - 1) + 1

f(n + 1) = 2 * fib(n) - 1 + 2 * fib(n - 1) - 1 + 1

f(n + 1) = 2 * fib(n + 1) - 1

### Example

fib(8)=34

so  recursive calls= 2*34-1=67

ans=67-1(for first call)

fib(4)=5

so recursive calls= 2*5-1=9

ans=9-1(for first call)

### Also fib(n) can be calculated in o(logn)

so overall complexity reduces to o(logn)

O(logn) for finding fib(n) and O(1) for finding recursive calls

but your code takes exponential time

Comment: Don't you think @user3386109 comment makes sense? The first call to `fib` should be considered recursive (any references)?

Comment: @KcFnMi No it has no sense. A call is a call that's all, every call counts as any other one. But this does not change anything at the end... The asymptotic behavior is the same.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I right?

Here's an easy way to check your results:

```
> ./fib 8 | grep "k:" | wc -l
67
```

That is, I ran your program at the command line and piped the output to `grep` to filter the output. Since every call to `fib()` produces exactly one output line containing `k:...`, the number of those lines should be the same as the number of calls to the `fib()` function. I further piped the output from `grep` to `wc -l`, which counts the number of lines, and the result is 67.

As @weathervane points out in a comment, changing the `r++` to `++r` would increment `r` before evaluating it in the `printf()` call, so you'd get the right value displayed. Or, you could just look at the output and notice that you're counting starting from 0:

```
k: 0 fib n: 8 +
k: 1 fib n: 7 +
k: 2 fib n: 6 +
k: 3 fib n: 5 +
...
```

Since your count is zero-based, you have to add one to get the total.

Comment: Don't you think @user3386109 comment makes sense? Only self calls are recursive, don't you think?

Comment: @KcFnMi That just comes down to how you want to count. `fib()` is a recursive function, and it's called 67 times. If you don't want to count the call from `main()` then your 66 is correct, and you can check that the same way I did above. You could also count the call from `main()` but not calls to `fib(0)` and `fib(1)`, since they return a value without recurring. I didn't realize that you were asking a question about semantics.